# Why do elixir guides say to use quote and unquote inside of a macro definition

Tags: int, elixir, metaprogramming

I have just started learning about macros in elixir. I am currently reading the metaprogramming-elixir book.

Right at the start of the book there is an example of how to create a macro called say. This macro will take an expression like `5 + 5` and return a string of `"5 plus 5 is 10"`...

```
defmacro say({:+, _, [lhs, rhs]}) do
  quote do
    lhs = unquote(lhs)
    rhs = unquote(rhs)
    result = lhs + rhs
    IO.puts "#{lhs} plus #{rhs} is #{result}"
    result
  end
end
```

I am wondering why we need to use the `quote` and `unquote` macros when we are defining our own macro?

```
defmacro say({:+, _, [lhs, rhs]}) do
  result = lhs * rhs
  IO.puts "#{lhs} plus #{rhs} is #{result}"
  result
end
```

Wouldn't the second version of the macro return the exact same answer?

Is there something that I am misunderstanding with the way macros work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are supposed to return AST. AST will be injected directly into the place where the call to macro was made from. This will happen during *compilation stage*.

That said, the latter will evaluate the result of the multiplication, **put the message to `stdout` during compilation stage** and inject a constant, representing the result, in place of the macro call. This macro would accept only compile-time constants, it won’t accept e.g. variables:

```
say(5 + 5)                       # works
with foo <- 5, do: say(foo + 5)  # raises
```

---

**The former will produce an actual AST for *evaluation*.**

Comment: Aaah. That makes sense. Thanks again :)